# Y axis inverted when running graph. How can I flip it?

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a program that takes input from the user as equation coefficients and creates the graph for that specific equation.

For example, let's take the equation x = y.
The graph then represents a straight line that goes through the center, from the bottom-left diagonal to the top-right one.

I am using bitmap, and, as you know, resolution in computers goes from top to bottom (0 to n) for Y and left to right (0 to n) for X.

The problem is that Y is inverted no matter what I try.

y = 0; (used as actual number, in real life, which represents y component at origin)
yGraph = 400 (origin of an 800x800 window).

I tried writing yGraph as y + 400 in a for function.

I tried writing in graph.SetPixel(xGraph, -yGraph, Color.Red); yGraph as negative, which of course wouldn't work as resolution pixels go from 0 to 800, not into negatives.

```
for (x = -400; x <= 400; x++)
{
    xGraph = x + 400;
    y = Convert.ToInt32(Form1.b*x+Form1.c);
    yGraph = y + 400;
    if(yGraph > 0 && yGraph <= 800)
    {
        graph.SetPixel(xGraph, -yGraph, Color.Red);
    }
    x++;
}
```

For any ax + b = 0 function, in which a > 0, the line should go from below the x axis to above it. Here it never did. It always switched places.

Comment: `yGraph = 400-y;`?

Comment: Well, that is how graphics work on a computer as opposed to a math coordinate system. To find a suitable transformation you will need to understand the size of your canvas!

Comment: That did it, thanks! @David